# how can we get from $x \equiv 4 \pmod 9$ to $x \equiv 1 \pmod 3$

Tags: number-theory

I want to solve the system:

$$ x \equiv 1 \pmod 3 , x \equiv 2 \pmod 5, x \equiv 3 \pmod 7, x \equiv 4 \pmod 9, x \equiv 5 \pmod {11}$$

The numbers $3,5,7,9,11$ are not pairwise coprime,especially the numbers $3,9$ are not coprime.

According to my notes, $x \equiv 4 \pmod 9 \Rightarrow x \equiv 4 \pmod 3 \Rightarrow x \equiv 1 \pmod 3$

But..how can we get from the relation $x \equiv 4 \pmod 9$ to this one: $x \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$ x \equiv 4 \mod 9 $ means $x = 9k + 4$ for some integer $k$. that means $x = 3(3k + 1) + 1$ and $3k+1$ is an integer which means $x \equiv 1 \mod 3$

Comment: I understand...Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2):

$x\equiv4(\text{mod }9)$ is equivalent to:

$x-4=9k (\text{ for some integer k})\implies x-3-1=3(3k)\implies x-1=3(3k+1)$

or, $x\equiv1(\text{mod }3)$

Comment: Nice,thak you!!

Answer (score 1):

Since 3 is a factor of 9, $x \equiv_9 4 \Rightarrow x \equiv_3 4 \Rightarrow x \equiv_3 1$